# double to int conversion always results in 0

Tags: java

I am attempting to cast a java double into an int which is always resulting in 0. I have printed the values out to the console to try and get a better idea of what might be happening although it isn't helping.

4.849401383433042E-10 <- value stored as a double.

0 <- the result after attempting to cast to an int.

I am attempting to cast by int i = (int) myDouble;

Thanks.

Comment: Did you expect the result of the cast to be some other value?

Comment: Uh, but that's a really tiny decimal part.  Notice the scientific notation.  So `0.000 000 000 48...` would be 0.

Comment: @rgettman I assumed 4.849401383433042E-10 would cast to 5 as an int. I assume i assumed wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @user3075268 you forgot about the exponent in the end, so in that case it will be still zero, without exponent You would cast it to 4

Comment: Very wrong. Why on earth would such a tiny number cast to 5? 0 is exactly the right answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Ah right now i feel stupid. Thanks I haven't done much work with doubles so wasn't aware of what the -10 meant. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `4.849401383433042E-10` is similar to scientific notation.  That value is equivalent to 4.849401383433042 * 10<sup>-10</sup>, or 0.0000000004849401383433042.

When you cast it to an `int`, the [narrowing primitive conversion rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) specify that the value is rounded towards 0 to yield an `int`, so the result is `0`.

> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3).

Without that `E-10` part it would result in not `5`, but `4`.

Comment: Just realised this now, feel extremely stupid. I've not worked with doubles before so wasn't aware what the -10 stood for. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

The value 4.849401383433042E-10 is equivalent to 0.0000000004849401383433042.

When this is cast to an integer, the value becomes 0. Remember that integer casting does not do any kind of rounding, they merely take what is before the decimal. For example, examine the following code.

```
double x = 9.99999;
int x_int = (int) x;

System.out.println("X is: " + x_int);
```

This prints out:

X is 9

Also to keep in mind is things like integer division. Examine the following code:

```
int i = 3 / 5;
double j = 3.0/5.0;

System.out.println("I is: " + i + "\n" + "J is: " + j);
```

This prints out:

I is: 1

J is: 1.4

Answer (score -2):

Try using the Integer class provided by Java.

Double dblObject = new Double(myDouble);

int cast = dblObject.intValue();

Comment: This does not address the problem of why the expected output is incorrect.

Comment: Not only is does that not solve the problem, but this is also really bad coding practice.